# reuse form, tree, kanban view in the website module

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-11, odoo-view

I'm working in odoo-11, I have created a module **my_contact** where I extend from **res.partner** to add the fields I need, like **facebookId**, **emailVerified, maritalState**, etc., and I have modified the views **form, tree,** etc., to show the new fields, this is the example of the extended form view:

```
<record id="res_partner_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">My Contact Form</field>
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="vat" position="before">                    
                <field name="marital_state"/>
            </field>
            <field name="email" position="before">
                <field name="facebook_id"/>
            </field>
            <field name="email" position="after">
                <field name="email_verified"/>
            </field>
        </field>
    </record>
```

up here all right. I need to make a website where I show all the contacts, for that I specify that my module '**my_contact**' depends on the **website** module, I would like to reuse the views I have extended, to show the form view previously shown, I do the following:

1. I create the website.page:

   ```
   <record id="contact_index_page" model="website.page">
       <field name="name">Contact Index Page</field>
       <field name="website_published">True</field>
       <field name="url">/contacts</field>
       <field name="view_id" ref="res_partner_form_inherit"/>
   </record>
   ```
2. I create a website.menu to navigate to the view:

   ```
   <record id="my_contact_menu" model="website.menu">
       <field name="name">Contacts</field>
       <field name="page_id" ref="contact_index_page"/>
       <field name="parent_id" ref="website.main_menu"/>
   </record>
   ```
3. I create a path in the controller to render the view:

```
@http.route('/contacts', auth='user', website=True)
def index(self, **kw):
    return http.request.render('my_contact.res_partner_form_inherit')
```

I check in the external identifiers that the path '**/contacts**' in the controller executes the view that I created by extending the original view, however, when I navigate to the path '**/contacts**' it says:
**ValueError: View 'my_contact.res_partner_form_inherit' in website 1 not found.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because you cannot reuse a form view to be rendered with Qweb Engine as if it's defined as a template. The call to `request.render` it's intended to render templates(qweb views). It's not possible in Odoo out of the box

Comment: Thanks @axel-mendoza, for your response. So the solution is to rebuild the views?

Comment: Yes, somehow. Create the template intended for being used for website that will contain html with qweb tags that will be translated to the final html using the qweb engine. Because form views and all the backend views in general will be translated to the final html using the backend web client and their widgets